# Configure SonarQube's Quality Gate section using Jenkins' Job-DSL

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-job-dsl

Does someone know Jenkins' Job-DSL syntax to configure SonarQube's quality gate plugin section?

Answer (score 2):

One can use the [Configure](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) block of Job DSL to define custom elements. A related question is [Using Jenkins Job-DSL Configure block to place custom steps in particular positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548472/using-jenkins-job-dsl-configure-block-to-place-custom-steps-in-particular-positi).

The following script worked for me,

```
configure { project ->
    project / publishers / 'quality.gates.jenkins.QGPublisher' (plugin:'quality-gates@2.5'){            
        jobConfigData{
            projectKey('MY-PROJECT-ID')
            sonarInstanceName('SonarQube')                
        }            
    }
}
```

The script can be tested using "Job DSL playground" at http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Had to change 'quality.gates.jenkins.QGPublisher' to 'quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.QGPublisher'. Works fine then.

Comment: This does not work with the official sonar-quality-gates pluging (version 1.0.5). It causes a NPE. If I open the job and save it without changing anything, a lot of other properties are added and it works.